# How accurate is Vuforia Fusion compared with "pure" ARCore / ARKit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, arcore

I'm experimenting with *Vuforia Fusion* to be able to track an object and then use its new *extended tracking* system (which should use *ARCore/ARKit* if available) to track the detected object in space.

The problem is, no matter what settings I set, no matter even if I place the .aar ARCore plugin inside the *Plugins > Android* folder in the Unity editor (as mentioned in the Vuforia guidelines to integrate ARCore), the tracking will always be very inaccurate compared with the ARCore implementation without Vuforia.

I'm wondering if Vuforia Fusion really uses ARCore, because, as I said before, even if I don't put the .aar ARCore plugin inside the *Plugins > Android* folder, Vuforia Fusion still returns me that I'm using the PLATFORM_SENSOR_FUSION (aka ARCore).

Does anyone experienced the same behaviour? Or did you have different results?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: I have tested it for understanding tracking status and i have found some inconsistent behavior as well. For example, what i found was when you use fusion type as PLATFORM_SENSOR_FUSION you can not recover when you lose tracking even though this is a feature from ARCore. Also you can recover with VUFORIA_SENSOR_FUSION which they claim is error prone. I asked a [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778945/can-not-get-when-the-device-tracking-is-lost) about this as well but can not get an answer.

Comment: I hope that my answer to this SO question could be somewhat useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811770/are-there-any-limitations-in-vuforia-compared-to-arcore-and-arkit/

Comment: @alikanat thank you for your reply, maybe your problem could be related to mine in some way, hope you'll get an answer

Comment: @ARGeo thank you for your answer, unfortunately I already found your question and read all the answer but I didn't found mentions to the Vuforia imprecisions compared to ARCore (even though it is mentioned that ARKit is more accurate)

Comment: Almost all of Vuforia's features are near-similar to ARCore. And it is incorrect to compare Vuforia and ARCore. I suppose any comparison is subjective.

Comment: @ARCore if VuforiaFusion works as expected it makes no sense to use ARCore because Vuforia offers more than ARCore. First thing comes to mind  is object detection for example. But in my opinion Vuforia Fusion is a big mystery i have no idea how it works or even if it works to be honest.

Comment: Just for information, I verified and Vuforia actually uses the ARCore plugin in Unity, my test failed because I had to restart the editor after unloading the .aar plugin. However, I still don't get how does Vuforia work and how does it use ARCore uhm